# How to implement an if else condition in the code behind for ImageButton OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, slideshow

I am working on my website design and have already implemented a simple slideshow consisting of image buttons that would redirect users to different pages when they click on them. However the issue that I've noticed is that all of the images redirect users to the same page and I realized it was due to all the Images in the slideshow inheriting the method Response.Redirect("url")...then I tried to use an if else condition for example

```
if(ImageButton3.ImageUrl=="/Images/Homepage_Button.PNG")
{
 Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
}
```

However I have noticed that this method does not work. Do you guys have any suggestions, huge thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use a data-url attribute on your image buttons.  When you post back you can get the url off the `((ImageButton)sender).Attributes("data-url")` and redirect to that url.

Another suggestion, if you aren't doing anything else in the event handler, you could simply use links around images.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug this code? To see if it reaches the URL you specified?

You can do that by clicking on "Start with Debugging" in Visual Studio.

Another good bug ugly debugging method is to add an alert (MessageBox) inside the if sequence and see if it gets there. For example:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", ("The URL is " + ImageButton3.ImageUrl));
if(ImageButton3.ImageUrl=="/Images/Homepage_Button.PNG")
{
 Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
}
```

Edit: After seeing your comment, I suggest accessing this image like that (notice the @):

```
if(ImageButton3.ImageUrl=="@Images\Homepage_Button.PNG")
{
 Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion I relied through debugging that the get ImageUrl method does not retrieve the image url. Is there any other way to retrieve the url of an image button in C#?Thanks!

Comment: Adding an alert box in this manner *really is* ugly. Infact, alerts are ugly full stop. If you were to go down this route, at least use console.log()

Comment: Hey, I added an edit with the way *I* think may be right to access the image resource (look at the the @).